# Call map function outside a list to do computing on a given parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, map-function

How to call the map function when the primary function uses other param outside the list in which the calculations must be done.

Thus a simple example (my proper one is more sophisticated)

```
def sum_inc(lst_to_sum, inc_value):
   sum_val =  sum(dict(lst_to_sum))
   sum_inc = sum_val + inc_value
   return sum_inc 
lst1= [1, 34, 45]
val1 = 4
```

I want to call the map function on a such way but it outputted an error.

```
map(sum_inc(inc_value= val1), lst1)
```

Comment: What is the point of `dict` in `sum(dict(lst_to_sum))`? You don't need to convert a list of numbers into a dictionary in order to sum it.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: does not matter list or dict...   it's just an example to understand my need.

Comment: Then you should read [how to make a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @tomjn my speciifc need is too complicated to be posted here.. I just want to call map function with many arguments but some of them are not used directly in the computing

Comment: This isn't an example where you'd use map. Mapping *maps* an iterable to another iterable. For simplicity, we could say it just maps every element in your list to another element, returning a list. What you are doing is *aggregating*, which isn't what map is used for.

Comment: What is the intended output in your example? Also -- using the name of a function as the name of a local variable in a function is confusing at best.

Comment: I need to use multiprocessing with map function but my function have other params outside  the list to do calculation on... IT is a complicated function to do tf-idf on a corpus (machine learning concept)

Comment: `map(lambda x: sum_inc(x,val1), lst1)` would make more sense (and is the only natural reading of the intent behind `map(sum_inc(inc_value= val1), lst1)`), but with your example would still throw an error.

Comment: "I need to use multiprocessing" Please state that in your question! Multiprocessing has some restrictions that make the naive solutions unsuitable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways.

Lets start with a function that multiplies two numbers

```py
def mult(x, y):
   return x * y
```

We then want to apply this to every element in a list to get a new list.
We will multiply every element by `3` for this example.
The "pythonic" way to do this would be using a list comprehension

```py
l = [1, 2, 3]
out = [mult(x, 3) for x in l]
```

Simple and readable. Now let us say we want to use `map`. Note that the creator of python originally wanted to remove `map` from python 3. Read into that what you will.

`map` takes a function taking a single argument and an iterable. So we should just make a new function that fixes `y` e.g.

```py
def mult_by_three(x):
    return mult(x, 3)

out = list(map(mult_by_three, l))
```

It is annoying having to declare a function like this just to use it once, so we could instead use a `lambda`

```py
out = list(map(lambda x: mult(x, 3), l))
```

Yuck.

Yet another way is to use the `partial` function from the `functools` module

```py
from functools import partial
out = list(map(partial(mult, y=3), l))
```